# Concurrency in kotlin coroutine flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to this kotlin coroutine flow, am wondering that how could i achieve the concurrency inside the flow, Whereas according to the documentation it says `launch`,`scope` and `withContext` cannot be used inside the flow. without this How would i able to achieve the concurrency in kotlin `flow`
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Take a look at this post https://medium.com/@elizarov/kotlin-flows-and-coroutines-256260fb3bdb

Comment: @aiqency is there no direct approach? or is it possible to have nested flow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `channelFlow` builder. You can start a coroutine inside of it and emit the result once it's done. Its documentation states...

> Creates an instance of the cold Flow with elements that are sent to a
>   SendChannel provided to the builder’s block of code via ProducerScope.
>   It allows elements to be produced by code that is running in a
>   different context or concurrently.

You can check its official documentation and its usage [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html).